# UIButton Text Size Issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

I have the following code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"My Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = myCustomRect;
UIColor *fontColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.43 green:0.84 blue:0.86 alpha:0.9];
[button setTitleColor:fontColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cooperplate" size:9];
[button addTarget:self
                action:@selector(moreDetails:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

I am trying to add a button programmatically to the view.
MyCustomRect's parameters are (0,0,75,50).

Two things:
a) No matter what font I enter, it always shows the System font. 
b) The size also doesn't change at all. I tried increasing the font size and it doesn't change and I tried reducing the font size and it doesn't change either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means your font "Cooperplate" is not added to your application. Check if you have added this into your bundle and plist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your own custom fonts in your project as [mentioned here](http://lawrenceleach.com/using-custom-fonts-in-ios-5)

Once you add a custom font to your project, you can use it as,

```
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Cooperplate" size:24.0]];
```

> First, in XCode locate the application .plist file. Usually called,
>   [YOUR_APP_NAME]-Info.plist. Once you locate the file, add a new row of
>   key: "Fonts provided by application". XCode will create the first
>   key/value pair for you. Here is a screenshot of my .plist file entry.

[Image](http://getfile3.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2011-12-08/rrgIctBcxEvemquElmrfFpjtznmDwDdcrmlAFkohiHeJFtgbIFHgvkCsprwC/Screen_Shot_2011-12-08_at_11.17.34_PM.png.scaled500.png)

> Add the name of the font file in the "value" column. Be sure to spell
>   the name of the font file EXACTLY as it is in seen in the list of
>   files in your project. This is NOT the name you will be referencing
>   from within your UIFont statement. This is just so your app knows
>   where to find the font you will be referencing.
>
> Next, you need the
>   name of the fontface you are going to use. Now you reference it in
>   your app.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for UIButton

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(20 , 13, 200, 85)];
UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 185, 30)];
[title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkboard" size:14]];
[title setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
title.text=@"This is the title";
[title setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[btn addSubview:title];
[title release];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0]];
```

Comment: That worked. It probably means that "Cooperplate" font doesn't work with UIButton's label. Is there somewhere I can find a list of compatible fonts for UIButton?

Answer (score -1):

Use this line of code after : This should resolve the issue with size

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cooperplate" size:9];
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
```